Linked server connection issue when connecting from multisubnet AOAG
I have multisubnet AOAG setup on AWS EC2 servers as below.
Problem is that linked server won't work when failover happens or connecting through replica which is not in same subnet as linked server node
Node1a (Primary replica)
Node1b (Secondary replica)
ListenerName : Listener1L (with multi-subnet IP address)
Node2a (Primary replica)
Node2b (Secondary replica)
ListenerName: Listener2L (with multi-subnet IP address)
Linked-server: LS_List1L (connecting using Listener name - Listener1L)
Linked server works fine when Node 1a and Node2a acting as primary replica and are in same subnet
Linked server doesn't work when AOAG failovers from Node2a to Node2b and now Node2b acting as new primary replica since it's in different subnet compare to node1a using listener name through linked server.
What would be the best option to resolve this issue?
